# Java commands not working in command prompt

Tags: java, command-prompt

I want to compile and run my Java programs with Windows 10 command prompt. I discovered that only "java" command work, not "javac", "javadoc", and etc. I'm not sure how to make these commands work. I checked some similar questions relating to these issues, most of them are outdated and complicated.

I need some directions to run my Java programs in command prompt.

Comment: You shoud add path to JDK bin folder to your system PATH. E.g. "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin"

Comment: You probably have only the JRE on the system path. Therefore "java" works but the other commands cannot be resolved. Follow EvgeniyDorofeev's advice.